# How to set actions while click on popupTemplate in Arcgis javascript 4.0

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to set the actions while I click the popupTemplate, please find my code sample below,

> view.popup.on({action:[actionA,actionB] });

The console error is,

> Uncaught TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function                on.js:5

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    view.popup.on("trigger-action", function(evt){
      if(evt.action.id === "actionA"){
        doSomething();
      }
      else if(evt.action.id === "actionB"){
        doSomethingElse();
      }
    });
```